# Криво отображается шрифт unifont в терминале kitty

Tags: linux, консоль, шрифты, shell

С другими шрифтами (в т.ч. моноспейсными) всё нормально, но с unifont такие вот пробелы. В termite и alacritty такого нет.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/issues я б туда пошёл

Comment: Похоже на проблему рендеринга: выглядит как юникод, который каждый байт воспринялся отдельно (для рендеринга), поэтому каждый второй символ — пробел.